# Providing database access via java webservice

Tags: java, database, web-services

Our company is currently implementing a couple of tools for employee use, as i'm the only programmer within the company its fallen to me to develop these tools.

However i have little to no experience with webservices or java, so im a little stumped on some logic here. and hoping someone can give me some guidance

We have a mysql database hosted in the UK, this will provide the data for the tools that will be used both within the UK and outside of the UK by our other offices. I'm looking to provide access to the database via web services.

However having looked into this, I get the feeling i have missed something key. Right now I'm looking to create methods for every database table, so each table will need a select, update and delete method, since there are 20 odd tables, that means the web service would have 60 methods exposed!, is this normal?

It seems to me that there would be an easier way to do this but having little experience with java i'm at a loss, and my google fu has failed me thus far.

Could anyone give me some pointers on what the "usual" way of doing this is? and if there is some way that I've simply overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

**Web services should be written for each entity and not for each table**. An entity should be a logical one and not simply something very abstract. There can be multiple tables in your database to store the data for one entity. For example: You have an entity called 'Person' but assume that details of the person are stored in multiple tables such as 'PersonDetail', 'PersonContactDetails','PersonDependentDetails', etc. You can manipulate these tables data using webservices created for 'Person'.

**Web services operations can be mapped to database CRUD(CREATE,READ,UPDATE,DELETE) operations**. If you are writing RESTful webservices CRUD operations can be mapped to HTTP methods i.e. POST,GET,PUT,DELETE.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, as i mentioned above, the 20 tables i mentioned actually relate to the 20 entities, there are additional tables that would be joined with these, i should have made this clear in my original post, sorry about that.

Comment: @user1412240 In that case you have 20 entities in your system. You need to decide whether all the entities are public and need to be exposed in web services. Depending on that you can expose the webservices.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one typical approach, although it's a pretty big learning curve:

1. Create Data Access Objects (DAOs) to query the DB and convert from your relational data model to a java object model.  If extreme performance isn't a consideration (it isn't a consideration for most applications), consider ORM mapping frameworks like [Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html) or [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html).   You probably don't need one method per table.  Many times multiple tables make up one domain object.   For instance, in a banking app you might have a table called customer, and a related table called customer_balance.  If you just want to present a balance to a customer, you could have one domain object called "Customer", with a field called "balance".  Your Customer DAO would join customer and customer_balance to create a single Customer object.
2. Create services to wrap DAOs and apply your business rules to them.  Keep biz rules in the service as much as possible because it improves testability.  An example of a simple banking service method would be "withdrawMoney(amount)".  The service would pull the Customer from the DB via a DAO, then first check that the custom has at least "amount" in current balance, and then subtract "amount" from the current balance and save it in the database via the DAO.
3. Your web layer will call the services layer and present the data to the user and allow them to operate on it.   At some point, you may want your web layer to communicate with the services layer via a web service API, although that is probably overkill for early implementations.

As others have cited, the Java Petstore application is a good example of this approach.  Oracle doesn't maintain the Petstore app any longer, but volunteers have copied it to GitHub and are keeping it up to date with the latest J2ee versions.  Here's a link to the GitHub site:  https://github.com/agoncal/agoncal-application-petstore-ee6

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'll certainly look into what you have suggested, I notice most people giving the same example of using multiple tables for an entity, and while that is true for my database too, the 20 tables i listed are actually tables like customer, with extra tables providing additional information that will be joined. as such it still looks like i will be needing 20 DAOs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if every one of your 20 tables will require selection (HTTP GET), update (HTTP PUT) and delete (HTTP DELETE), you will probably need 20*3=60 methods.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to start off by having a read of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/partwebsvcs.htm#BNAYK) part of the Java EE 7 tutorial which will give you an overview of web service development. What you are suggesting though seem strange and perhaps not really what you want. If you want to expose every table to updates / deletes / etc then you'd perhaps be better off just opening the port to the database server but this is generally considered a bad idea.

I think you probably want to work at a higher level and pass around objects rather than database updates, lets say, for example you have a `Person` object in your application. You can pass that to and from your web application and client application and let the web application worry about putting it in the database, deleting it etc. Although there is nothing technically wrong with performing updates in the way you are suggesting I've not seen it done for many years.